# Create scatterplots with control variables

Tags: statistics, stata, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a scatter plot for two variables while partialing out for the effect of a control variable.

My regression is as follows:

```
reg y x z, robust
```

And if I wanted to make a normal scatter plot I would use the following code:

```
twoway scatter y x, mlabel(country) || lfitci y x
```

But now since I have the control variable ***z***, I don't know how to include that into the scatter plot.

Is there any other command that I can use for it? Thanks.

Comment: The answer sounds like an added variable plot. See `help regression postestimation plots`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to add a second control variable to the model to make the charts more interesting.

The easiest way to do this is with `margins`:

```
sysuse auto, clear
keep price mpg foreign weight

/* Expected Value with CI Varying mpg */
reg price mpg i.foreign weight, robust
margins, at(mpg = (10(5)30))
marginsplot, name(ci_only, replace) ylab(#10, format(%9.0fc))

/* Add Scatterplot and Modify Aesthetic Options */
reg price mpg i.foreign c.weight, robust

forvalues v = 1(1)5 {
    gen mpg`v'=5+`v'*5
}

margins, at(mpg = (10(5)30)) generate(exp_price)

marginsplot, addplot(      ///
    scatter exp_price1 mpg1, ms(oh) mcolor(maroon) mlwidth(vvthin) || ///
    scatter exp_price2 mpg2, ms(oh) mcolor(maroon) mlwidth(vvthin) || ///
    scatter exp_price3 mpg3, ms(oh) mcolor(maroon) mlwidth(vvthin) || ///
    scatter exp_price4 mpg4, ms(oh) mcolor(maroon) mlwidth(vvthin) || ///
    scatter exp_price5 mpg5, ms(oh) mcolor(maroon) mlwidth(vvthin) || ///
, below) ///
legend(off) ylab(#10, format(%9.0fc)) recastci(rline)   ///
ciopts(lpattern(shortdash) lcolor(navy) lwidth(thin))   ///
plotopts(lcolor(navy) mcolor(navy) lwidth(thin) mlwidth(thin) ms(Oh)) ///
name(ci_plus_scatter, replace)
```

[image]

The first plot shows the expected price varying mpg for all the cars, but keeping foreign and weight as observed in the data.

[image]

The second plot adds a scatterplot of modeled values and plays around with some of the aesthetic options. It's a bit more work to add these.

---

Your comment is more of a restatement than a definition of PO. Reading between the lines, you may want something like this:

```
sysuse auto, clear
reg price mpg weight, robust
gen price_po_mpg = price - _b[mpg]*mpg
tw (scatter price_po_mpg mpg) (lfitci price_po_mpg mpg, ciplot(rline))
```

This CI will be off since it doesn't take into account the estimation of the mpg coefficient, so I would not take it too seriously. Alternatively, if you meant setting age to the median in the expected value and varying education, that can be accomplished with the `margins` command.

Comment: What graphing scheme are you using here? It's very aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. It's a custom scheme using my company's colors and a custom font that I've been working on and forgot to turn off here. It's similar to the one [here](https://medium.com/the-stata-guide/stata-graphs-get-those-fonts-right-c38d35625142). Other options [here](http://repec.sowi.unibe.ch/stata/palettes/help-colorpalette.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful to know, but with margins, I can't really make line of best fit like in a traditional scatterplot. I also don't have a variable like mpg to define the intervals. Would avplot make more sense?

Comment: But you don’t have a line in (y, x, z) space. You have a surface in a cloud. Without doing something about the other dimensions, like I have done, you cannot just draw a line. There is also nothing special about mpg, and you can define values at which to evaluate the expected value for any variable. If you clarify what you seek to do and your constraints, I would be happy to take another stab. As is, I can’t tell if avplot makes sense since

Comment: It would help if you define partialing.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to make a scatterplot between wages and education while partialing out (controlling for) median age. And these are the only three variables that I have.

Comment: @tish See above.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov thanks so much! this works for what I was trying to figure out.